# how to fix Cookies not setting in laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, cookies

I'm trying to set a `httpOnly` cookie for token but it's not saving cookie.

I'm trying to login users via `OTP` and when user entered correct `OTP`, I'll sign them in app and so far I've done it like below :

```
$user = User::where('mobile_number', $request->mobileNumber)->first();

if ($user) {
    Auth::login($user);

    $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

    $cookie = cookie('token', $token, 60 * 24 * 24); // 24 day

    return response([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'loggedIn',
        'user' => auth()->user(),
    ])->withCookie($cookie);

}else{
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'notExist'
    ], 200);
}
```

User will successfully login and if I refresh the page I should login again, and when I check `Application\Storage\Cookies in Firefox and Storage\Cookies in chrome` there's no sign of returned cookie(even if I don't refresh the page cookies won't be saved at all).

I'm using `Laravel Passport`, and so far, i don't think there should be any problem related to `VUE` side, since cookies not even saving in browser.

I've also tried to add more cookies to just test if everything work, but same problem happened again and nothing saved in browser.

I've also tried other solutions in `Stackoverflow` but they didn't worked.

[image]

Edit 01 : Removed refresh page...
Edit 02 : `Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` and Queue tested.

Comment: Try queuing your cookies and make sure `Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` this middleware is enabled in your Kernal.php

Comment: @SumitWadhwa I've trie Queuing and didn't worked.
And `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` was enabled by default.

Comment: Sidenote: are you aware that `httpOnly` cookies are not accessible by javascript? I cant really answer the question since its hard to tell what happens. You mention a "refresh the page" in your question but there's no explanation of what happens there.

Comment: @Flame yes, I'm aware. forget about whole refresh page situation, it's not saving at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. It looks like the problem was from Vue side actually. App URL was `127.0.0.1` for default in `env` file, but in Vue it was calling the API via `Localhost`, and it was working, but the cookie wasn't saved due to this conflict. When I changed it to `127.0.0.1` as default `baseURL` in Axios, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add cookie name in $except.

/app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cookie Facade that Laravel provides:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
 
Cookie::queue('token', $token, 60 * 24 * 24);
```

In your `Kernel.php`, search for `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` and uncomment it if it's commented.

Comment: Didn't worked...

Comment: it shouldnt matter if you use `Cookie::queue` or `response()->withCookie(...)`